# Comparing two columns to insert a different column value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to compare two columns (column A&C) and add another columns value (column D) if value in column C is found in column A.

Current situation:

[image: Current situation]

- COLUMN A = ART1, ART3
- COLUMN C = ART1, ART2, ART3, ART4
- COLUMN D = 2,
  4, 6, 8

I need the formula to give me the below in column B:

[image: Desired situation]

- COLUMN A = ART1, ART1, ART1, ART3
- COLUMN B = 2, 2, 2, 6
- COLUMN C = ART1, ART2, ART3, ART4
- COLUMN D = 2, 4, 6, 8

Thank you!

Comment: Use VLOOKUP(). It will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,C:D,2,FALSE),"")
```

and drag it down
Vlookup will match A1 to column C and return the corresponding value in column D (2)
False to return exact match